# angular ngOnChanges not detecting changes in component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a datatable, chart, and Latest value added label

- Table and chart are displaying time-series data that contains: the value time for the last 30 minutes and its numerical random value from 0 to 999.
- Every 10 seconds new object gets pushed into the array and the oldest one is deleted so only the last 30 minutes are showing all the time. Latestvalue label is displaying the latest value added

I am trying to figure out why the ngOnChanges in chart component is not detecting changes which it should because new object is pushed to the data array in main component  every 10 seconds, so the chart should be updated and redraw every time it does that.

Here is working stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znnnsp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.html,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Flabel%2Flabel.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Flabel%2Flabel.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.ts

main ts :

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  data: IData[] = [];
  latest: any = { time: 0, value: 0 };

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
    this.getLatestValue();
  }

  getData() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }
```

main html

```
<div class="row">
  <app-table (editedRow)="onRowEdit($event)" [tableData]="data"></app-table>
  <div class="column">
    <app-label
      [latestTime]="latest.time"
      [latestValue]="latest.value"
    ></app-label>
    <app-chart [chartData]="data"></app-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

chart ts

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input() chartData: IData[] = [];
  data: any;

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
    this.initChart();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initChart();
  }

  initChart() {
    const times = this.chartData.map((item) =>
      this.datePipe.transform(item.time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    );
    const values = this.chartData.map((item) => item.value.toFixed(2));

    this.data = {
      labels: times,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "First Dataset",
          data: values,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: "",
          tension: 0.4,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { IData } from "./interface";

const delta = 10000;

function getValue(): number {
  return Math.random() * 1000;
}

function getTime(index: number) {
  return Date.now() - index * delta;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class DataService {
  private data: IData[] = [];
  private lastValueData: Subject<IData>;

  constructor() {
    this.lastValueData = new Subject();

    for (let i = 179; i >= 0; i--) {
      this.data.push({
        time: getTime(i),
        value: getValue(),
      });
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      const value = {
        time: Date.now(),
        value: getValue(),
      };

      this.data.shift();
      this.data.push(value);
      this.lastValueData.next(value);
    }, delta);
  }

  public stream(): Observable<IData> {
    return this.lastValueData.asObservable();
  }

  public getData(): Observable<IData[]> {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      subscriber.next(this.data);
      subscriber.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code here.

Comment: added main component where i fill the data array with data, main html where i pass the data to the child component chart and chart ts where is the Input and ngOnChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your code a bit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ptkrd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts

Mainly, I changed your main.ts data inside the subscription using spread syntax: `this.data = [...data];`, and reworked the logic inside your data.service:

- your original `data` is now `rawData`, on which the code is applying all the changes and calculations, while I introduced:
- `data` that is just a BehaviorSubject returning the value of `rawData`, and finally:
- changed data.service getData() method to actually return (new) `data` observable.

If you're actually going to work with data coming from subscription to some api, it will be much easier, since you won't need to add all that dynamic code for updating the `data` value (now `rawData`).

Comment: That works great, thank you, If i wanted to display the changed values in the chart when i edit any of the rows in table do i need to call next() on the subject now or how would it work please ?

Comment: i added id property to the IData and i tried doing this ```onRowEdit(editedData: IData) {
    const index = this.data.findIndex((data) => data.id === editedData.id);
    this.data[index] = editedData;
  }``` but no luck

Comment: Check the same stackblitz link: I've modified the code. Check `editRow()` in table.ts and in template (one more param added) and note that I changed type of data.value input to number, and check  `setData()` in service.ts.